# How to edit a registry key for all users on a remote machine

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to set a registry key for all users on a remote machine.  I have a script that I've been using to edit registry entries in HKLM and it goes as follows:

```
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computername)  
$regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon",$true)
$regKey.SetValue("DefaultUserName",$hostname,[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String)
```

I also have a piece that retreives user SIDs that goes like this:

```
$sids = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -computername $computername | Where{$_.LocalPath -notlike "*$env:SystemRoot*"}).sid
```

I am wanting to do a foreach loop to edit a registry setting for each individual SID, but I am having trouble going from using'local machine' to 'user'/'sid'.  I have found ways to work with the user hive, but have been unable to find a way to plug in the sid.

Comment: Read up on the [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.2) [cmdlet](https://adamtheautomator.com/invoke-command/). Note. [PSRemoting must be enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-7.2), the hosts must be properly configured for it to work, and you must have permission to fo this.

Answer (score 0):

This connects to the RegHive HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

```
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computername)
```

But as you say you want to set something for all users it has to be (HKEY_USERS):

```
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Users', $computername)
```

If you want to set a key for all users the right path is:

```
#HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey(".Default")
```

If you want to set a key for a specific user the path is:

```
HKEY_USERS\[SID]
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey("[SID]")
#Sample how to loop
$sids = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -computername $computername | Where-Object {$_.LocalPath -notlike "$env:SystemRoot"}).sid

foreach ($sid in $sids){
    $regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey($sid)

}
```

Here `$reg.OpenSubKey("$sid")` you can add the path e.g. `$reg.OpenSubKey("$sid\Control Panel")`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Toni.  I had to play with the syntax a bit and I threw in a try/catch since not every profile would have the registry key I'm looking for, but here is my final result:

```
$computername=Read-Host -prompt "Enter computer name"
$sids = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -computername $computername | Where{$_.LocalPath -notlike "*$env:SystemRoot*"}).sid
$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Users',$computername)
foreach ($sid in $sids)
{
$regkey = $reg.OpenSubKey("$sid\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Search",$true)
try{$regKey.SetValue("SearchboxTaskbarMode","0",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::dword)}
catch{}
}
```